# 'XML Parsing Error' when loading non-XML data via AJAX in Firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox

I'm using Firefox 66.0.5 and jquery 3.4.1.

When trying to load a simple text file (with arbitrary content) via:

```
$.ajax({
    url: './foo.txt',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data) { console.log(data); }
});
```

The file's contents are displayed in the console but I also receive an `XML Parsing Error: syntax error`.

It seems like Firefox just ignores the `dataType` and attempts to parse the file as XML anyways. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is the `Content-type:` header that the server is sending?

Comment: The `dataType:` option is processed by jQuery, not the browser.

Comment: If the server sends `Content-type: text/xml`, the browser will try to parse it as XML. jQuery ignores this, but the browser still logs the warning.